# Объединение двух таблиц по диапазону ip-адресов

Tags: mysql

1-ая таблица:

```
Id (int), date (date), number (int), ip (varchar) (int невозможно из-за точек)
Primary key - id, number.
```

2-ая таблица:

```
From_ip, To_ip, Country, Descr
```

Необходимо выбрать запросом столбцы `date, number, ip, country, descr`.

Каким образом объединить эти две таблицы по значению `IP` из 1-ой таблицы, попадающему в **диапазон** *ip-адресов* из 2-ой таблицы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ip (varchar) (int невозможно из-за точек)

я бы рекомендовал хранить всё-таки в `int` — это значительно оптимальнее с точки зрения производительности, например, озвученной вами же задачи.

а для преобразования можно воспользоваться функциями [`inet_aton()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) и [`inet_ntoa()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa).

---

а ниже — примерный ответ на вопрос:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba538/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1 (id int, date date, number int, ip int);

create table t2 (from_ip int, to_ip int, country text, descr text);

insert into t1 values
  (1, now(), 1, inet_aton('111.111.111.111'));

insert into t2 values
  (inet_aton('111.0.0.0'), inet_aton('111.255.255.255'), 'рф', 'блок1');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.date, t1.number, inet_ntoa(t1.ip) as ip, t2.country, t2.descr
  from t1, t2
  where t1.ip between t2.from_ip and t2.to_ip
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba538/3/0)**:

```
|                   date | number |              ip | country | descr |
|------------------------|--------|-----------------|---------|-------|
| July, 16 2015 00:00:00 |      1 | 111.111.111.111 |      рф | блок1 |
```